# Dynamic inheritance in Scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, composition

I have an abstract grandparent class named `Grandparent`, and a parent class named `ParentOne`, and several children classes named `ChildOne`, `ChildTwo`, `ChildThree`, ... and so on.

They are written as following:

```
abstract class Grandparent {
    val value: Int
    def print(): Unit = println(value)
}

class ParentOne extends Grandparent {
    override val value: Int = 1
}

class ChildOne extends ParentOne
class ChildTwo extends ParentOne
class ChildThree extends ParentOne
```

What I am aiming for is to provide a method for changing the `value` printed in all `Child` classes to, for example, `2`. I want the method to be as simple as it can.

The result will be something like creating a class `ParentTwo` as following and making all `Child` classes inherit it instead of `ParentOne`.

```
class ParentTwo extends Grandparent {
    override val value: Int = 2
}
```

But I know this is impossible, since we can't *dynamically change* the superclass. I want to make the structure of the library to be better, to achieve the task above. What would be the simplest way to make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

> What I am aiming for is to provide a method for changing the

Which I'll take as a method which should mutate the value for all the children classes, right?

If so, you could use the companion object of the `Parent` class to store a **variable** which could be changed at will:

```
abstract class Grandparent {
    def value: Int
    def print(): Unit = println(value)
}

object Parent {
    var mutableValue: Int = 1
}

class Parent extends Grandparent {
    override def value: Int = Parent.mutableValue
}

class ChildOne extends Parent
class ChildTwo extends Parent
class ChildThree extends Parent
```

Example of use:

```
pablo-pablo@ val c = new ChildOne() 
c: ChildOne = ammonite.$sess.cmd6$ChildOne@4ad10ef2
pablo-pablo@ c.value 
res12: Int = 12
pablo-pablo@ Parent.mutableValue = 30 

pablo-pablo@ c.value 
res14: Int = 30
```

Comment: I guess this is the best solution so far. However I can't deny that it has a feeling of using global variables.

Comment: @SuhjinPark Kind of but no exactly so, it is more like static variables constrained to a class context. You could make `mutableValue` private and add a method `changeValue` to `Parent` object which would be the only way to change it. You could make that method package private...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a immutable solution, then you'll have to introduce a member. Currently you inject the `value` using inheritance. But this cannot be changed at runtime.

One solution would be having the child classes carry the value:

```
class ChildOne(value: Int) extends GrandParent
```

Then the client has to specify the value on each object creation. You can introduce a builder, so the client has to specify it only once:

```
case class ChildBuilder(value: Int) {
  def buildChildOne = new ChildOne(value)
  def buildChildTwo = new ChildTwo(value)
}

> builder = ChildBuilder(2)
> val child1 = builder.buildChildOne
> val child2 = builder.buildChildTwo
```

I don't know if this is a viable solution. Somehow I have the impression that you should change your approach all together. But I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I have thought about builder classes but I have more than 15 classes that inherit from the `Grandparent` class and people could even add more classes that inherit from it. So builder classes may be inappropriate. I am finding a flexible solution, but it seems so hard to think of. Maybe I have to reconsider the application's structure.

Answer (score 0):

## Using implicit parameters

Require the `value` method to acquire the value through an implicit parameter.
The client can either create an `Environment`, or you can provide premade environments that can be `import`ed.

Note that the instance will not own the `value`. It has to be provided on each method call.

```
case class Environment(value: Int)

trait Parent {
  def value(implicit env: Environment): Int = env.value
}

class Child1 extends Parent
class Child2 extends Parent
//client code

implicit val env = Environment(2)

(new Child1).value == 2
(new Child2).value == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution using mixins

```
trait AbstractParent{
  def valueP: Int
}

trait Parent1 extends AbstractParent{
  val valueP = 1
}

trait Parent2 extends AbstractParent{
  val valueP = 2
}

abstract class Child1 {self: AbstractParent =>
  def value = self.valueP
}

abstract class Child2 {self: AbstractParent =>
  def value = self.valueP
}



//client code

val c11 = new Child1 with Parent1
val c21 = new Child2 with Parent1
val c12 = new Child1 with Parent2
val c22 = new Child2 with Parent2
```